TSearchBox: AutoSelect when the SearchBox is focused?
In a Windows 11 VCL Application in Delphi 12.1, I have a TSearchBox. I want to auto-select the SearchBox text when the SearchBox is focused. I have tried the following:

Set AutoSelect to True at design time:


Selecting the SearchBox text at run time:
procedure TForm1.SearchBoxMainEnter(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  SearchBoxMain.SelStart := 0;  
  SearchBoxMain.SelLength := Length(SearchBoxMain.Text) - 1;  
  SearchBoxMain.SelectAll;  
end;



Unfortunately, the SearchBox text is not selected.

Setting AutoSelect is sufficient. Note that just clicking into the control will not trigger the  selection. That is the same as with a plain TEdit. Try using TAB instead.

Also, it's redundant to manually select all the text yourself and then use SelectAll. Pick one or the other. Using both is just useless CPU cycles and keystrokes. SelectAll does the same as setting SelStart and SelLength, but does it in a single line of code and significantly fewer keystrokes.

SearchBoxMain.SelectAll; does work, selecting all the text.  However, what happens when you click in the edit seems to be this:

The mouse click causes the focus to change to SearchBoxMain, thereby triggering the call to SearchBoxMainEnter.
The same mouse click is then responded to as if you'd clicked into selected text, by immediately clearing the selection.

The solution is to not handle the OnEnter event, but to respond to mouse events.  The following code worked for me.  It uses the search box's Tag property, but you could use another variable if you were already using the Tag for something else.
procedure TForm1.SearchBoxMainMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if SearchBoxMain.Tag = 1 then SearchBoxMain.SelectAll;
  SearchBoxMain.Tag:=0;
end;

procedure TForm1.SearchBoxMainMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not SearchBoxMain.Focused then SearchBoxMain.Tag:=1;
end;

procedure TForm1.SearchBoxMainMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SearchBoxMain.Tag:=0;
end;

What happens depends on the scenario:
You tab into the search box
None of the event handlers above are invoked, so everything works normally.  (If you had handled OnEnter, tabbing into the control would also call the event handler.)
You click into the search box when it doesn't have the focus

SearchBoxMainMouseEnter is called as in order to click in the search box, you must first move the mouse over it.  As it's not already focused, it sets the Tag to 1.
SearchBoxMainMouseDown is called as you click the search box.  If the Tag = 1, it calls SelectAll, which does work*.
The Tag is reset to 0, so subsequent mouse clicks do not select all the text again.
SearchBoxMainMouseLeave is called to reset the Tag to 0 (although it already is).

* On a few tests, the selection was from the start up to the mouse position.  I assume that was due to how I clicked.
You move the mouse across the search box but don't click into it.

SearchBoxMainMouseEnter is called.  As it's not already focused, it sets the Tag to 1.
SearchBoxMainMouseLeave is called to reset the Tag to 0.  Without this, if you then tab into the control, then click into the selected text, SearchBoxMainMouseDown will be called, and as the Tag is still set to 1, this will instantly reselect the already-selected text, not the expected behaviour

